# Linux shell script logical error

Tags: linux, unix, rhel

I have got following command to get privillages list from mysql

```
# mysql -u root -p -B -N -e"SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@localhost"
```

where I want to replace 'root' with Vuser variable and localhost with VHost variables, I am not able to judge where the double quotes ends and how to put $Vuser and $Vhost.

Please some one can guide...!

Thanks

Comment: Read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -u root -p -B -N -e"SHOW GRANTS FOR '$Vuser'@'$Vhost'"
```

should work. $XXX variables get expanded by the shell in double quotes. The single quotes won't hurt because, within the double quotes, they lose there special meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution seems to be this. No single quotes. The double quotes keep everything after -e a single argument and they also allow variable expansion:

```
mysql -u root -p -B -N -e "SHOW GRANTS FOR $Vuser@$Vhost"
```

As @Guntram pointed out, the single quotes around `$Vuser` are necessary according to the MySQL spec. But it seems to work without those as well, at least with MySQL 5.5.31.

Comment: You need the single quotes around the username though, according to the mysql syntax docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-grants.html.